Playwright button click inside iFrame just Waiting
I'm newer to Playwright and I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm working within a framework that is providing iFrames without an id or class.

I am trying to click on one of the buttons in the embedded control

It will just sit here

I can't use page.FrameLocator because it requires a selector and I don't have one to give it.
Here is the control in the iframe that I am trying to click on


Please see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Can you convert this to a [mcve] of text, along with the site under test (or a repro of it), so I can more easily run your code? Thanks.

You're selecting the button first and then the assuming more actions label is a child of the button. This is not the case, more actions is the value of the title and aria-label attributes on the button itself.
I believe what you need is ...
await page.getByRole('button', { name: /more actions/i }).click();
or because the title is "more actions" ....
await page.getByTitle(/more actions/i).click();
